# LaunchOptions.locationKey in UIApplication didFinishLaunchingWithOptions nil

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I'm monitoring significant location updates via `CLLocationManager`. When the app is killed and there is a location event, both `App Delegate` and `Scene Delegate` are being launched in the background appropriately. But `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location` is nil in the `launchOptions`

According to the Apple documentation:

> For a scene-based app, examine the options that UIKit passes to the application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:) method to determine why it created your scene.

However, the `connectionOptions` in the `SceneDelegate` does not have an appropriate alternative for the location key.

How do I know my app was launched from a location event?

iOS Version: 14.4.2

Comment: aledap, did you got any solution here?

Comment: From SceneDelegate no. However, I completely removed the SceneDelegate and methods from the app. Then I was able to get the UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location in the launchOptions in AppDelegate

Comment: If you find a solution via Scene Delegate, please do share. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I have also tried everything with Scene Delegate, but no success. If you see the methods for ConnectionOptions, there is no relevant method which can contain the location key. All methods are somewhere or the other user invoked, like clicking a link etc.

Comment: Yep, that is the issue.

Comment: Sounds a bit stupid, but what I did is launching a notification "App started from SLC" in the appDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and this notification pops up only when the SLC launches the app.

Answer (score -1):

try this function when application is killed and notification will be tapped this function is called

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```